# Ensure that WebAPI2 routes are matched before MVC Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web application which uses both MVC and WebAPI2.  I would like for requests to always be matched up with WebAPI2 attribute routes before matching manually configured MVC routes.  I have tried calling `configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` before I call `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)` but this does not seem to work.

Is there any way to ensure the WebAPI2 routes will always have precedence?

Comment: The convention for Web API routes is to prefix the route with "api" and even a version "v1".  This will segregate them from the MVC routes, so why do you care about the order unless you're sharing a convention between MVC and Web API?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go.  Use VS to create a new controller.  Be sure its called someController, where some is the name of your controller, it must end in "Controller".  Be sure your class inherits ApiController...

```
public class someController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/test/{name}"), HttpGet]
        public string Router(string name)
        {
            return "Your name is: " + name;
        }        
     }
```

Also add this in your global.asax file.

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();  //This will remove XML serialization and return everything in JSON.

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
    }
```

In above, the api route is waiting for HttpGet, You can use HttpPost too, and use FormDataCollection to get posted form data.  Note how you can parameterize your APIs with {someparameter}

The above is quite simple, and the API controller can serialize most objects that implement serialization.  If not can use NewtonSoft or something.